# Option values in zurb foundation 3.2 custom form selects

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I am using a form select to change location.href. My question is about how zurb foundation custom forms work.

1. Does selection of an option from a foundation custom form select element (which are implemented with divs), also set the selected attribute on the corresponding option value on the hidden (standard) form select?
2. Is it the intent is that the developer should hard code duplicate form elements (as in the markup below), or is jquery.foundation.forms.js supposed to handle replacement in the background?

Thanks!

```
<form action="#" class="custom">
<select id="subcatselect" style="display:none;">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
<div class="custom dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="current">This is a dropdown</a>
    <a href="#" class="selector"></a>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. No, the framework automatically inserts the custom HMTL. You just code the original select element.